# Single Page Application Tracking with Analytics: no virtual pageviews in dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application, pageviews

I'm trying to use some virtual pageviews on my single page application (Angular)

I set the js code as follows:

```
ga('set', 'page', pageviewurl);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

where the var *pageviewurl* could be something like:

```
'/form/w/toyota?from=hp#step=2__from=js'
```

But I'm not able to see anything related these virtual pageviews on Analytics dashboard...

am I doing something wrong?
Or in which section of the dashboard can I get pageview data?

Thanks

Comment: asking a question about how to use ga api is a programming discussion. And it can also be useful for other people

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my question just to confirm that the js code is correct.
After some time, by accessing to Analytics dashboard, virtual pageview data is visible in the section *Real time -> content*